# How to use passport with koa-generic-session()?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, koa, passport-local

I've created a Koa application which uses passport with a local authentication strategy. I'd like to use the module [koa-generic-session](https://github.com/koajs/generic-session) so I can store the session data in Redis.

How do I use those two together?

I found this repo which does this but it doesn't really seem to use the sessions and I am not sure whether it is correct: https://github.com/dozoisch/koa-react-full-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Koa, but I am with Express and Passport.)*

I've looked through the link you provided, and here's how they use koa-generic-session with passport.

In the [server.js](https://github.com/dozoisch/koa-react-full-example/blob/master/server.js) file, the following lines refer to configuring Passport.

```
08 - const passport = require("koa-passport");
13 - const config = require("./config/config");

38 - require("./config/passport")(passport, config);
40 - require("./config/koa")(app, config, passport);
```

Line 38 is the traditional passport config file, which simply sets up serialization and deserialization.
Line 40 brings in [koa.js](https://github.com/dozoisch/koa-react-full-example/blob/master/config/koa.js) and passes it the app, config file, and passport variables.

The following code is from koa.js:

```
04 - const session = require("koa-generic-session");

18 - app.keys = config.app.keys;
```

Looking at koa.js, koa-generic-session is assigned to the variable session.  This variable is later called here:

```
35 -  app.use(session({
36 -      key: "koareactfullexample.sid",
37 -      store: new MongoStore({ url: config.mongo.url }),
38 -   }));
```

On line 18, `app.keys` is initialized as the documentation for [koa-generic-session](https://github.com/koajs/generic-session) calls for.  While the project you linked uses a MongoStore with koa-generic-session, you can simply replace that constructor with a koa-redis constructor, as is shown in the [koa-generic-session](https://github.com/koajs/generic-session) documentation.

Lastly, Passport is initialized:

```
41 - app.use(passport.initialize());
42 - app.use(passport.session());
```

This code is similar to using Passport with Express, as that's all Passport needs to manage authentication through a session.